# Navigation and hover links

Tags: html, css, image, hover, nav

My hover states for my navigation was working perfectly. I moved on to my next pages to add more things and suddenly now my hover links and navigation is not working. It's not the browser because it was working fine before.

I had even validated both html and css and no errors occured, please help!

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Project2d</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="pages/page-2.html" target="page2" title="page2">
        <img src="img/gallerybubble.png" alt="gbubble" class="gbubble">
      </a>
      <a href="pages/page-3.html" target="page3" title="page3">
        <img src="img/aboutbubble.png" alt="abubble" class="abubble">
      </a>
      <a href="pages/page-4.html" target="page4" title="page4">
        <img src="img/videobubble.png" alt="vbubble" class="vbubble">
      </a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <img src="img/homepanel.png" alt="homepanel" class="homepanel">
    </main>
    <img src="img/mangaportfolio.png" alt="title" class="title">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a </nav> code as well it seemed to not show up

Comment: Can you show us your `styles.css` code?

Comment: its too long to add in comments lol

Comment: i could post another question if you could look on my profile and helo me?

Comment: **You are absolutely shouldn't comment your code!** Please [edit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4zDjq.png) your question and add the relevant code there. Once you did this, add a comment and tell everybody that you updated your question. To nutify specific user, you need to type `@` then his user name

Comment: Definitely need to see the related css as well. Can you set up a demo on codepen.io or similar with the relevant bits of code?